Capital gain on partial sale
Purchased 6 acres with old home and barn for $415k, purchase did not separately assign or allocate values to land/home/barn — sold home with 1 acre for $200k five years later - how is capital gain on the partial sale determined?
Thanks!
note: there is no mortgage.

Hire a CPA, do a cost segregation study, the whole shebang. Good luck!

Please tag or comment with your jurisdiction, tax rules vary around the world and this is an international site.

what values were assigned when the property was subdivided in preparation for the sale? Was there a mortgage on the property when you purchased it, and is there still a mortgage?

In USA and no mortgage
